# Udp client working in java but not in android

Tags: java, android, netbeans, network-programming, android-networking

I have tested the program in netbeans it is working fine but it is not working in android. It is not receiving any data and getting blocked at this line but same code in netbeans is able to receive data. No error or exception is thrown while execution.Thanks for any suggestion.

```
    import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
        import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
        import java.nio.ByteOrder;
        import java.nio.channels.DatagramChannel;

        public class StarterThread implements Runnable {

            Thread t;
            DatagramChannel channel;


            StarterThread() {
                t = new Thread(this, "Starter Thread");
                System.out.println("Starter Thread : " + t);
                t.start();
            }

            public void run() {
                try {
                    channel = DatagramChannel.open();
                    channel.connect(new InetSocketAddress("192.168.43.62", 49191));
                    String newData = "START\r\n";
                    ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(190);
                    buf.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);

                    buf.clear();
                    buf.put(newData.getBytes());
                    buf.flip();
                    channel.write(buf);
                    int i = 0;
                    while (true) {
                        Log.i("Info", "In while loop");
                        buf.clear();
                        Log.i("log i", "" + i);
                        InetSocketAddress client = (InetSocketAddress) channel.receive(buf);
                        buf.flip();
                        Log.i("TimeStamp", " " + JIHelper.getUnsignedInt(buf.getInt()));
                        System.out.println(new String(buf.array(), "UTF-8"));
                        i++;
                        Log.i("log i", "" + i);
                        if (i % 10 == 0) {
                            newData = "KEEP-ALIVE\r\n";
                            Log.i("Message sent", "KEEP-ALIVE SENT");
                            buf.clear();
                            buf.put(newData.getBytes());
                            buf.flip();
                            channel.write(buf);
                            if (i == 100)
                                i = 0;
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }

        public class DisplayActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
         public void sendStartPacket(View view) {
        new StarterThread();
        }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you use Android >= 5.0, DatagramChannel.receive() doesn't work. You need to use DatagramChannel.read() instead.

Comment: I need the blocking feature if data is not available https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/DatagramChannel.html#receive(java.nio.ByteBuffer)

Comment: You can use DatagramChannel.read() as Blocking Mode by using DatagramChannel.configureBlocking().